# Windows 10 -- Casting only part of screen

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, whiteboard

For context, I am going to be teaching a 180-person math course at a university. I use a Microsoft Surface.

Here's what I would like to be able to do:

I want to be able to have the Microsoft Whiteboard app open on most of the screen, and some notes open on the rest, but I only want the whiteboard to be projected. Like what PowerPoint does, except that I want to use a whiteboard app instead of a PowerPoint presentation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows 10 Snap to edge to divide the screen
https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/snap-windows-10

Or,

You can use the apps in Windowed mode (not full screen) and drag the different edges to the size you wish.

Both ways have their advantages.  I use the latter way